# Find first non matching row with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering if there is anyway to see where a match function failed in vba? I want to be able to delete rows in a spreadsheet that do not match what is in the function. I am using an error handler to detect non-matches.

```
match = Application.match(Key, rng2, 0)

If IsError(match) Then
MsgBox ("NEW ROW!")
End If
```

Comment: *where a match function failed in vba?* What do you mean by this? You have adequate error handler to detect non-matches.  What are you actually trying to do??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test the result:

```
Sub fhjshf()
    s = Application.Match(a, b, c)
    If CStr(s) = "Error 2042" Then
        MsgBox "Match failed"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the first non matching row in VBA try that:

```
result = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("MATCH(TRUE,(" & rng.Address & "<>" & key & "),0)")

If IsError(result) Then
    MsgBox ("No new rows")
End If
```